# Doxygen: auto-reference of macros and enum elements

Tags: c, doxygen

I use doxygen 1.8.8 for documenting C project, I have `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT` set to `YES`.

Say, I have a macro documented like that:

```
/**
 * My macro
 */
#define MY_MACRO
```

Then, I mention this macro in the comments for some function, like this:

```
/**
 * My function uses `MY_MACRO` heavily
 */
void my_func(void) { ... }
```

In this case, `MY_MACRO` isn't a reference. After a lot of experimenting, I found some ways to make doxygen to make reference:

- specify it like this: `\ref MY_MACRO`. I don't like it because (a) it is not so convenient to write and to read in comments; (b) font isn't monospaced. I tried to combine it with backticks, it doesn't work;
- specify it like this: `MY_MACRO()`. I don't like it because, obviously, these parentheses suggest like macro is parametrized, but it is not;
- specify it at the bottom of comment, like this: `@see MY_MACRO`. I don't like it because it's not convenient to read, it would be much better if macro is referenced inline.

So, how to make it referenced just in the comment for function?

**UPD:** my doxyfile: [http://vpaste.net/FuIk4](http://goo.gl/olkjV0)

Comment: What are the settings for ENABLE_PREPROCESSING, MACRO_EXPANSION, PREDEFINED, EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF, EXPAND_AS_DEFINED.

Comment: @Rich ENABLE_PREPROCESSING=YES, MACRO_EXPANSION=NO, PREDEFINED=DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS, EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF=NO, EXPAND_AS_DEFINED is empty. I updated my question: added link to complete doxyfile

Comment: Strange, I've not seen this behavior before.  Perhaps disabling SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS would fix it?

Comment: @Rich no, nothing changed. Do you mean that for your projects enum elements and non-parametrized macros are autolinked? If yes, could you please share your doxyfile and probably project, if you have something open-source?

Comment: I'll have to do some digging - my memory is a bit weak here.  Does Doxygen behave differently if MY_MACRO has an explicit value?

Comment: @Rich no, behavior is the same. Actually, it autolinks only data structures (e.g. for `struct MyStruct`, `MyStruct` is a link), and symbols with trailing parentheses (i.e. functions and parametrized macros). But enum names, enum element names, non-parametrized macros, typedefs aren't autolinked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [autolink docs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html), we should prepend macro name, enum item or enum name with a `#`:

```
/**
 * My function uses `#MY_MACRO` heavily
 */
void my_func(void) { ... }
```

Then, `MY_MACRO` becomes a link.

Comment: I had missed a doxygen comment on my constant. This is tricky! (Also, for my function references in a C file to work, I needed a @file comment at the top)